# Two table combined selection fail

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables A and B. Both have `id='1111'` (string). If we do:

```
select A.* from A where id='1111'
```

and

```
select B.* from B where id='1111'
```

they both return results. When we do:

```
select A. * , B. *  from A, B where A.id=B.id and A.id='1111'
```

it returns nothing. Why?

Comment: What is the type of the ID column ? is it the same in both tables ?

Comment: You have a bunch of questions that have been answered and has obviously helped you, but you have not [accepted them](http://u.sbhat.me/t6SXUH). Please do else people may be not be inclined to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select A.* , B.* from A inner join B ON A.id=B.id where A.id='1111'
```

Comment: it also cannot get the result. and it seems (select A.* , B.* from A inner join B ON A.id=B.id where A.id='1111') has no difference from my selection sql: select A. * , B. * from A, B where A.id=B.id and A.id='1111'

Comment: A left join B on A.id=B.id where A.id='1111' has no data A right join B on A.id=B.id where A.id='1111' has no data

Comment: are u not getting the desired output?

Comment: sorry for typo      A left join B on A.id=B.id where A.id='1111' has no data A right join B on A.id=B.id where A.id='1111' has no data

Comment: is there any contents related to id='1111' in both the tables?

Comment: yes if I only search one table. both has data.  I have try again, now  A left join B where A.id='1111'  it has A's data now but B's data does not show. while right join, no data

Comment: listen if both the tables have id='1111' only then the output will be displayed else zero rows

Comment: select * from A where A.id='1111' it has data. select * from B where B.id='1111' it has data. while select A.*, B.* from A, B where A.id=B.id and A.id='1111'  it has no result